# Complex model on PYMC3 - Nonlinear Hierarchical model ?

Tags: python, probability, bayesian, pymc

I'd been studying the concepts of probabilistic programming using Pymc3 in the past couple of week and I have a question on how to implement a particular model, I will describe it next:

I have a set of  *N* data elements, and a matrix *NxN* defining the interactions between each other of those elements (the matrix is symmetric). I also have a property *E* for each element, I want to model this property as it follows:

[image]

What the model says is that, the energy of a element M is a weighted sum over all the other elements in the data set. The function d(M, M_i) is known ( is the NxN matrix I described before)

I want to model the weights alpha_i and sigma using Bayesian inference.

My try so far goes like this:

```
indx = np.arange(0, N   )
# The index for the N elements 
def estimator( alpha ,x , sigma , ):
    # My idea is that this estimator returns the estimated value for the energy for a given set alpha, x , and sigma
    return T.sum(  alpha*T.exp( -1/(2.0*sigma**2 )*x**2  )  )


with pm.Model() as hi_model:

    # Positive prior on sigma, N positive priors for the alphas 
    sigma = pm.HalfCauchy( 'sigma' , beta = 1 , shape = 1 )
    alpha1 = pm.HalfCauchy( 'alphas' , beta = 1 , shape = N  )
    # An error parameter 
    sigma_e = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma_e' ,  beta = 1  )
    tau_e = sigma_e**-2
    # The energy estimator build using the function above. 
    # D2s is an NxN matrix, whose column i is a vector of length N
    #representing the interaction of the i element with all the other N elements 
    energy_est =  estimator( alpha1 , D2s[indx] , sigma  )  
    ee = pm.Deterministic( 'muu' , energy_est )
    y_like = pm.Normal('y_like', mu= ee , tau=tau_e, observed= energy_smp[:N]  )
```

Pymc3 allow me to build and sample from this model without errors, but I'm not being able to use the sampled alphas an sigma to "predict" the N energies I'm giving as observed, I'm off by many orders of magnitude. So I'm concerned if the model is being understood as I want or if I'm missing something and thats not the way to build this kind of model.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: The models looks fine to me. Could you provide a minimal working example? There are a couple of minor details like, you don't need to specify the shape of `sigma`, do you? and you can directly use ` sigma_e ` for the `sd` of normal (no need to use `tau`).

Comment: I will try to provide an example later, i'm currently at work.   I let the model doing more sampling at home, to see if I'm able  to get better results.  Still there is something with the model that doesn't seem right, but I don't have much experience.